# How do I pass a parameter to a controller from a directive?

Tags: angularjs

My HTML looks like this

```
<td currency-convert idrVal="{{(btcAsk.btcValue * btcAsk.btcAmnt).toFixed(2)}}"></td>
```

**The AngularJS code**

The controller has the method:

```
$scope.convertIDRtoUSD = function(idrValue) {

    return CurrencyConversions.convertToUSD(idrValue, 'IDR');
};
```

And the directive looks like..

```
bitcoinApp.directive("currencyConvert", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        idrval: '@'
    },
    template: '<span class="has-tip" tooltip="convertIDRtoUSD({{idrval}})" tooltip-animation="false">{{idrval}}</span>'
};
});
```

This is currently not calling the convertIDRtoUSD method.

Reading online, I think I'm supposed to use the Isolate Scope "&" but have not had success so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to word this as best I can, so bear with me! Your template contains a method. At run time, it expects this method to be present on the current scope. However, at that point, the scope is the isolated scope you created with the directive, and simply contains the value of idrval, so that method is undefined.

You need to *either* add the function convertIDRtoUSD() to the scope of the directive, or pass the function *into* your directive along with idrval. If you choose the former, you'r directive might look like this:

```
bitcoinApp.directive("currencyConvert", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        idrval: '@'
    },
    template: '<span class="has-tip" tooltip="convertIDRtoUSD({{idrval}})" tooltip-animation="false">{{idrval}}</span>',
    link: function(scope) {
        scope.convertIDRtoUSD  = function(idrValue) {
            return CurrencyConversions.convertToUSD(idrValue, 'IDR');
        };
    }
};
});
```

If you want to pass the function in, and the function exists on the controller, your html would look something like this:

```
<td currency-convert my-func="convertIDRtoUSD(val)" idrVal="{{(btcAsk.btcValue * btcAsk.btcAmnt).toFixed(2)}}"></td>
```

And your directive:

```
bitcoinApp.directive("currencyConvert", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        idrval: '@',
        myFunc: '&'
    },
    template: '<span class="has-tip" tooltip="myFunc({val: idrval})" tooltip-animation="false">{{idrval}}</span>'
};
});
```

Some things to note - the attribute name of the function should be 'dash-named' not camel-case named, and parameters to the function passed into the directive have to be passed an an object with named values.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I added the function to the scope of the directive. The function doesn't seem to be called though.. only displayed as literal text. [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kmbzu2eu/2/)

Comment: [I updated your fiddle so that it works.](http://jsfiddle.net/kmbzu2eu/5/). The issue was you had your curly braces in the wrong place - you want the tooltip to be the result of the evaluated expression _{{convertIDRtoUSD(idrval)}}_. You don't need {{idrval}} since its just a number anyway.